# What does pull out mean exactly in the context of a car?

Tags: meaning, phrasal-verbs

> “The two of them walked toward the road and the stone marker. Behind them, other cars were **pulling out**. A woman began screaming abruptly. Unconsciously, Garraty and McVries drew closer together. Neither of them looked back. Ahead of them was the road, wide and black.”
> ———Excerpt From the Long Walk

To me, pulling out feels like driving away. However, there seems to be more to it. Pulling out feels like involving some change of direction when the car drives away? Not sure if my mental image is correct tho..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this context, to "pull out" means to drive out of the place where they were parked.

This action may involve going back and forth to manoeuvre out of a tight spot, but it could also mean just driving straight forward out of a driveway or parking spot.

Comment: In that case, can I replace pull out with driving away?

Comment: @Ray No. "Drive away" means leave the area. It's possible to pull out of a parking space and not drive away.

Comment: @MichaelWokeHarvey I guess I got the meanings in both cases, but how does it lead to this double meaning? How are this driving thing and bed thing connected?

Comment: @Ray Don't worry about not understanding it. He's just making a joke about sex.